# Does an Android Studio Linux arm64 version exist?

Tags: android-studio, arm64

Does an Android Studio Linux arm64 version exist?

I think now is a good time to support it since the new [Mac M1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Air_(Apple_silicon)#Third_generation_(Retina_with_Apple_silicon)) machine is arm64 and [some work is being done](https://asahilinux.org/) to run Linux on top of it.

Also I am developing with [Flutter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flutter_(software)) which (as far as I understand) already supports Linux arm64.

But I can't find any GitHub repository for Android Studio to request support. Is there any?

More people that asked on other forums:

- [On Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidStudio/comments/o9k53g/how_to_install_android_studio_on_linux_for_arm64/).
- And another one [on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidStudio/comments/q4wugw/linux_arm_possible_to_run_android_studio/).
- Chromebook is based on Linux, so here is one for installation [on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidStudio/comments/e8r9or/how_to_install_android_studio_stable_release_on/).

Comment: My suspicion is the qemu ARM KVM support is holding everything back. Would not surprise me if exactly that comment was uttered by the lead producer manager

Answer (score 5):

I didn’t find anything official, but I could run the full [Android Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio) (AS) on my cellphone and tablet with Linux ARM64 (aarch64) sideloaded with [Termux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Termux). And I worked on several projects from my phone.

#### Run Android Studio

I'm making a YouTube video explaining all the process, but it is
quite simple.

On most operating systems, Android Studio is running on top of [Java 17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_17) (ago 2023), so you just need to download the Linux version of Android Studio and replace de "jbr" folder with any OpenJDK 17.

#### SDK download error (emulator)

When you open AS for the first time, it will try to download the SDK packages, but it will fail because the emulator for aarch64 exists, but *we don’t need it*. So you just have to add some fake emulator files to ANDROID_SDK_HOME/emulator
and it’s done. I have a ZIP file with some files here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/17BuoXgtLG33tkgePLyWerfuzMcILtYtU/view?usp=drivesdk

To replace the emulator in my case, use `adb connect localhost` (or with Wi-Fi pairing), because Android Studio is literally running on an Android Device. But you can connect with any device by the network.

With this, you have your Android Studio running.

#### ARM Build Tools

But, in my projects, ADB, appt2 and other build tools do not work, so... you have to compile yourself. But like [Pritesh said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71067886/does-an-android-studio-linux-arm64-version-exist/71067910#71067910), by community effort, we have all tools for build tools 33.0.3 built at the [release page for *Android SDK tools*](https://github.com/Lzhiyong/sdk-tools/releases).

After download, you need to replace the build-tools binaries that AS downloads for those on the repository above.

The problem is, especially for the **aapt2** (Android Asset Packing Tool) that "creates APK files" is downloaded by Gradle on demand. so... we need to force Gradle to use a specific binary.
Just put on or create a *[gradle.properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties)* file with:

```
android.aapt2FromMavenOverride=/YOUR_ANDROID_SDK_PATH/build-tools/aapt2
```

#### Not Working

For now, the only thing that is not working for me, is the Compose Layout Preview. The plugin seems to be native code (it is the only explanation for me).

Comment: Hi, how did you manage to connect Android Studio from the Linux distribution back to the same phone? I tried to run adb connect localhost but got connection refused. I tried to scan the WiFi QR code from the WiFi debugging in settings but it did not work.

Comment: Using wifi depuration, u just need wifi do first pair and connect first time. On developers options turn on wifi depuration and on linux use adb pair and adb connect using localhost as ip. Just need the wifi to firt connect, you can run adb tcpip 5555. After that, u can run adb connect localhost anytime until restart the phone. U can send a message on my telegram @victorwads if u need.

Answer (score 1):

I think they want to delay *everything* until [QEMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QEMU) supports [KVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel-based_Virtual_Machine) aarch64. It doesn't make any sense to me, but it's the only reason I can think of.

I think I know all the ARM Android tools and all of them are running on ARM by community effort.

I can also add that a similar large project placed ARM support in a community fork: https://github.com/NVIDIA-Omniverse/PhysX/discussions/58. But Google is strangely silent on this idea or anything else about it.

I placed minor footnotes that might be controversial and useless below this line and they can be skipped.

---

How well their QEMU fork is getting along with the main QEMU development I have no inkling about. My personal experience is annoyance with most changes in their Android fork of QEMU.

The community relations with Android has always been tense and frigid. Just some minor spurious tentative circumstantial influences on this feeling. GitHub is in their "outgroup" and it affects their communication negatively. They haven't shown any interest in easier communication with the users since the days of *[Google Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Developers#Google_Code)*. Terminal support has been nonexistent and they are even slightly annoyed with the terminal Android community. It is difficult for a scientist to work in an environment that is so obsessed with the whims of the marketplace as Google has become.

Comment: So Qemu is like rosetta from Apple? Wikipedia says that it has a Stable release. Also Android Studio is based on JetBrains ide and as far as I know it does not support arm as well. I do know that vs code have ide for arm so you can use it for now I guess

Answer (score 0):

#### Yes, the Stable version is released for the Chromebooks

*[How to install Android Studio (Stable Release) on an ARM64 processor (Chromebook)](https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidStudio/comments/e8r9or/how_to_install_android_studio_stable_release_on/)*

Comment: "sudo dpkg --add-architecture amd64" That's not ARM last time I checked